How to transition from @import to @use without changing every file?
I saw that SCSS deprecated the use @import, and I'm struggling to update my code to use the suggested @use.
I currently have one main file that imports all files, starting with the variables, like so:
@import "./variables";
@import "./homepage";

Except for this main file, no other files have any imports.
I thought I could change it to this:
@use "./variables" as *;
@use "./homepage";

But now when I use one of the variables in homepage.scss it says the variable is undefined. If I understand correctly I would have to add a @use statement to every single file to make it work, but I don't want to do that...
I've also tried using @forward, but no luck yet... I feel like I'm missing something. Or is structuring my code like this really not possible anymore?
I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction to update my code without having to add a @use statement in every single SCSS file.

This question is similar to: Having only one base SCSS @use import in entire React application?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
